# proportions of a range of numbers = >1

Tags: r

I am trying to determine the proportion of a range of numbers for subsets on a long dataframe. (The aim is to write a function.)

```
below.green<-mean(results$Value <0.04)
green.amber<-mean(results$Value >0.04:0.4)
amber.red<-mean(results$Value >0.4:4)
red.plus<- mean(results$Value >4)

meanresults <- c(below.green,green.amber,amber.red,red.plus)
```

e.g.1

```
Values <- c(0.1501,0.1276,0.0838,0,0,0.4544,0.2573,0.1788,1.291,1.4737,1.8191,
0.5986,4.5846,4.9056,2.4809,2.1021,3.3741,0.0085,0.0302,0.0033,0.0405,0,0,0,0,0,
0.3262,0.0462,0.2536,0.3661,0.4311,0.4719,0.8482,2.3731,0.656,0.3967,0.0399,
0.0302,0.2723,0.3833,0.5907,0.3725,0.0258,0.0483)

sum(meanresults)
#[1] 1.247892
```

e.g.2

```
Values2 <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0726,0.0077,0.0444)

sum(meanresults)
#[1] 1
```

When my proportions are returned on some subsets the proportions equal >1 (see e.g. 1). 
Other sites the proportion total =1 (e.g. 2) this seems to happen only on sites where Value <0.4.
Where am I going wrong?

I have looked at multiple QAs on the site and haven't found similar examples.

Comment: Very likely `mean(results$Value >0.04:0.4)` isn't what you are after. I guess the correct line should be `mean(results$Value >0.04 & results$Value<0.4)` and the same for the others. A quick way to do what you want to do: `prop.table(table(cut(Values,c(0,0.04,0.4,4,Inf))))`.

Comment: Thank you for both answers Nicola, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the sequences.

Try making your code with the R function `between` (data.table package).

Some examples:

```
> 0.04:0.4
[1] 0.04
> 0.3 < 0.04:0.4
[1] FALSE
> between(0.3, 0.04, 0.4)
[1] TRUE

> 0.4:4
[1] 0.4 1.4 2.4 3.4
> c(0.3, 0.5) > 0.4:4 #Only use the first value
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> between(c(0.3, 0.5), 0.4, 4)
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Look at the help (?between) and the parameter incbounds to set the intervals.

```
> between(c(0.3, 0.5), 0.3, 4)
[1] TRUE TRUE
> between(c(0.3, 0.5), 0.3, 4, incbounds = FALSE)
[1] FALSE  TRUE
```

Regards!!

Comment: What is this "*R function `between`*" you speak of?

Comment: between is a function of data.table package [link](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.5/topics/between).

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the link, I'm familiar with the package. But the link should be in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Juan, look forward to using it in the future.